# Regex - How to capture an arbitrary string appearing anywhere in a known string?

Tags: c#, regex, string

I need help making a regular expression. I have a string that is known at compile time, let's call it `SpecificString`. I also have another string whose value is **not** known. Let's call it `ArbitraryString` for example purposes. The input string is made up of one `SpecificString` that contains `ArbitraryString` in it at any position or is adjacent to `ArbitraryString`. I want a regex pattern that captures `ArbitraryString` from the input string for me to use later.

---

Examples:

- example format: input string => captured group's value
- `SpecificArbitraryStringString` => `ArbitraryString` // inside
- `SpecHAHAHALOLificString` => `HAHAHALOL`
- `SpecificStringYOLO` => `YOLO` // adjacent
- `SpecificStrisadng` => `sad`
- `itsABea8tifulDaySpecificString` => `itsABea8tifulDay` // also adjacent
- `Show to be a heartbreakerpecificString` => `how to be a heartbreaker`
- `SpecificSt this is the last example ring` => `this is the last example` (in the output of the last example stackoverflow.com omitted the spaces at both ends for some reason, just ignore that and assume they are there)

I was only able to come up with a regex whose length grows linearly with the length of `SpecificString` making it very difficult to maintain. Any ideas?

Pseudocode (not necessarily valid C#):

```
static string GetArbitraryString(string input)
{
    const string specificString = "SpecificString";
    var regex = // regex pattern to find
    var match = regex.Match(input);
    string arbitraryString = match.CapturedGroups[0].Value;
    return arbitraryString;
}
```

*Only regex answers will be accepted.*

**edit: the new question: Does an elegant regex solution to this even exist?**

Comment: Any particular reason why you will only accept Regex-related answers? It seems like a non-Regex solution would be easier.

Comment: @Abion47 I know. But I really really want to know whether an elegant regex solution to this exists. And I really hope this comment won't get this question closed.

Comment: If you programmatically generate the regex whose length grows linearly with the length of `SpecificString`, would it still be difficult to maintain?

Comment: @SinaIravanian no but the answer certainly wouldn't be elegant. In that case I would just solve it without regexps. The more I think the less possible the existence of an elegant solution seems.

Comment: This doesn't even smell like something you can match elegantly with a context-free grammar. Maybe as a CSG or unrestricted grammar?

Comment: @SebastianLenartowicz yup. It is impossible to match without the context (`SpecificString`). But does that mean that an elegant solution doesn't exist?

Comment: I mean, it's not elegant, but `^(.*?)?S(.*?)?p(.*?)?e(.*?)?c(.*?)?i(.*?)?f(.*?)?i(.*?)?(.*?)?c(.*?)?S(.*?)?t(.*?)?r(.*?)?i(.*?)?n(.*?)?g(.*?)?$` will do what you want (just iterate over the capture groups afterwards to extract the string).

Comment: @SebastianLenartowicz this is close to but not quite elegant in my opinion. My solution was much uglier/longer. I may accept that as an answer though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here's the best I've got in terms of a regex answer, using chained [conditionals](http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html) to ensure you only get the string you want (though it's still pretty damn inelegant in my opinion):

```
^(.*)?S(?(1)|(.*))?p(?(2)|(.*))?e(?(3)|(.*))?c(?(4)|(.*))?i(?(5)|(.*))?f(?(6)|(.*))?i(?(7)|(.*))?(?(8)|(.*))?c(?(9)|(.*))?S(?(10)|(.*))?t(?(11)|(.*))?r(?(12)|(.*))?i(?(13)|(.*))?n(?(14)|(.*))?g(?(15)|(.*))?$
```

Then, all you have to do is iterate over the capture groups and pick up the one that isn't empty. Simple as that.

And, since you're in C#, you can even use named capture groups with the same name for all of them. Whichever one gets picked up will be the value of the named capture.

[Demo on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/MwS0Ly/2)

Comment: Not quite perfect, since in the first example it captures the group "Arbitrary" and then the second instance of "String" as separate groups rather than capturing the whole inner "ArbitraryString".

Comment: @Abion47: Fixed. But it's a lot nastier now :P

Comment: Yeah, I maintain that a non-Regex solution would be much easier and more elegant in this case. This is interesting from an informational point of view, but I would never want to use that code in practice.

Comment: No argument here.

Answer (score -2):

I would use a dictionary

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] inputs = {  
                                "input string => captured group's value",
                                "SpecificArbitraryStringString => ArbitraryString // inside",
                                "SpecHAHAHALOLificString => HAHAHALOL",
                                "SpecificStringYOLO => YOLO // adjacent",
                                "SpecificStrisadng => sad",
                                "itsABea8tifulDaySpecificString => itsABea8tifulDay // also adjacent",
                                "Show to be a heartbreakerpecificString => how to be a heartbreaker",
                                "SpecificSt this is the last example ring => this is the last example"
                              };

            Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            string pattern = "^(?'name'[^=]+)=>(?'value'.*)";
            foreach (string input in inputs)
            {
                Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
                dict.Add(match.Groups["name"].Value.Trim(), match.Groups["value"].Value.Trim());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you don't read question details before you post, do you? You are literally using captured group values that are provided by me when I explicitly tell that these values are not known beforehard and have to be extracted from an input string using the regex.

Comment: No I am not.  Just test data to test my code.  Don't you want tested code and instead of code that doesn't work?